# Python question about dictionary(debugging)

Tags: python

I know this is relatively a basic question. I am trying to verify if given two sentences are synonym based on the given dictionary.
For example if dictionary is [(movie, film), (john, jack)] then "john likes movie" and "jack likes film" are synonym thus the function below will return true.
I changed each of two strings into the list of words by using lower/strip/split, then I tried to compare both lists by using for and if condition. I can't figure out where I did wrong.

```
def synonym_checker(synonyms, sentences):
    a=sentences[0][0]
    b=sentences[0][1]
    a.lower()
    b.lower()
    a.strip()
    b.strip()
    aw=a.split()
    bw=b.split()
    import string
    at = a.maketrans('','',string.punctuation)
    bt = b.maketrans('','',string.punctuation)
    ase = [w.translate(at) for w in aw]
    bs = [w.translate(bt) for w in bw]
    dictionary = dict(synonyms)
    this = True
    for i in range(0, min(len(ase), len(bs))):
        if ase[i] != bs[i]:
            if (bs[i] != dictionary[ase[i]]) and bs[i] not in [first for first, second in dictionary.items() if second == ase[i]]:
                this = False
    if (len(ase) != len(bs)):
        this = False
    is_synonym = this
    print(ase)
    print(bs)
    return is_synonym  # boolean

a = [("film", "movie"), ("revadfsdfs", "ads")]
b = [("I really want to watch that movie, as it had good fdf.", "I really want to watch that film, as it had good fdsaa")]

print(synonym_checker(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your error happened on

```
dictionary[ase[i]]
```

Because what you did here is actually

```
{'film': 'movie', 'revadfsdfs': 'ads'}['movie']
```

When your "movie" is not a key, but a value.

{'film': 'movie', 'revadfsdfs': 'ads'}
  .. ^......... ^..............          ^ ............         ^
  key .....value  .......   key      .......  value

The true problem here in my opinion is, your approach is not correct. Because dictionary is a one-way information, so when you want to check both 'film' to 'movie' and 'movie' to 'film', don't use a dictionary.

It also looks like you are trying to do something unnecessarily complicated for what you are trying to achieve.

```
a.lower()
b.lower()
a.strip()
b.strip()
```

Does not do anything to the actual program

The way you named your variables are also very hard to read, so maybe pick a proper name instead.